# Writing a recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I need to write a function which verifies parentheses are balanced in a string. Each open parentheses should have a corresponding close parentheses and they should correspond correctly.

For example, the function should return true for the following strings:

> (if (any? x) sum (/1 x))
>
> I said (it's not (yet) complete). (she didn't listen)
>
> The function should return false for the following strings:
>
> :-)
>
> ())(

OPTIONAL BONUS

Implement the solution as a recursive function with no mutation / side-effects.

Can you please help me out in writing using C# because I'm new to .NET technologies.

Thanks.

Here's what I've tried so far. It works for sending parameters as open and close brackets, but I'm confused with just passing a string... and also I should not use stack.

```
private static bool Balanced(string input, string openParenthesis, string closedParenthesis)
    {

        try
        {
            if (input.Length > 0)
            {
                //Obtain first character
                string firstString = input.Substring(0, 1);

                //Check if it is open parenthesis
                //If it is open parenthesis push it to stack
                //If it is closed parenthesis pop it
                if (firstString == openParenthesis)
                    stack.Push(firstString);
                else if (firstString == closedParenthesis)
                    stack.Pop();

                //In next iteration, chop off first string so that it can iterate recursively through rest of the string
                input = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 1);
               Balanced(input, openParenthesis, closedParenthesis);   //this call makes the function recursive
            }

            if (stack.Count == 0 && !exception)
                isBalanced = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = true;
        }

        return isBalanced;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done? We can help you, but we won't do your homework for you :D

Comment: pls find my code here which works for sending parameters as open and close brackets. but im confused with just passing a string...and also I shoulld not use stack

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of string.substring(0,1), you can use str[0], and check with '{' instead of "{".

Comment: Hint: Use a `Stack`. It will make your life easy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: thanks unlimit but I should not use stack here.

Comment: I'd change: `Can you please help me out in writing using C# because I'm new to .NET technologies.` to `can you please do this for me because I want the extra credit ... `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use any recursion method for such a simple requirement, just try this simple method and it works like a charm:

```
public bool AreParenthesesBalanced(string input) {
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
      if (input[i] == '(') k++;
      else if (input[i] == ')'){
        if(k > 0)  k--;
        else return false;
      }
  }
  return k == 0;
}
```

Comment: May be "foreach(Char letter in input)" will be slightly better to read than "for(int i = 0;..." loop format

Comment: @DmitryBychenko agree!

Answer (score 2):

I have used the startIndex and increment with each recursive call

```
  List<string> likeStack = new List<string>();
  private static bool Balanced(string input, string openParenthesis, string closedParenthesis , int startIndex)
{

    try
    {
        if (startIndex < input.Length)
        {
            //Obtain first character
            string firstString = input.Substring(startIndex, 1);

            //Check if it is open parenthesis
            //If it is open parenthesis push it to stack
            //If it is closed parenthesis pop it
            if (firstString == openParenthesis)
                likeStack.Add(firstString);
            else if (firstString == closedParenthesis)
                likeStack.RemoveAt(likeStack.Count -1);

            //In next iteration, chop off first string so that it can iterate recursively through rest of the string
           Balanced(input, openParenthesis, closedParenthesis , startIndex + 1);   //this call makes the function recursive
        }

        if (likeStack.Count == 0 && !exception)
            isBalanced = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception = true;
    }

    return isBalanced;
}
```

Comment: @rajeshAlbert Is it ok to use the List , because stack is using the LIFO which we can achieve using list also. I have updated my code by using the List<String> rather than stack. Just have a look

Answer (score 2):

How's this recursive version?

```
    public static bool Balanced(string s)
    {
        var ix = -1;
        return Balanced(s, false, ref ix);
    }

    private static bool Balanced(string s, bool inParens, ref int ix)
    {
        ix++;
        while (ix < s.Length)
        {
            switch (s[ix++])
            {
                case '(':
                    if (!Balanced(s, true, ref ix))
                        return false;
                    break;
                case ')':
                    return inParens;
            }
        }

        return !inParens;
    }
```